# On windows: using a hook to capture global input events in Java

Tags: java, hook

### Intro

For a simple test tool recorder, how to capture left mouse click in Java.

To keep this short, last time I did this, it involved using code outside JDK sandbox. So I wrote a DLL in C++ and used it with JNI - I do not want to do that again.

Now I have tried using [jintellitype](http://code.google.com/p/jintellitype/) and it does a great job on hotkeys (what I also want to do), but I can't seem to be able to find a way to capture left mouse click. ( [example on jintellitype](http://melloware.com/products/jintellitype/quick-start.html) )

### About answer

I assume that the answer will be one of following:

#### Answer 1

Below:
( `x` = unique nr; `y` = integer as binary modifier keys, like `ctrl` and `alt`; `z` = key code)

```
JIntellitype.getInstance().registerHotKey(x, y, z);
```

What are the correct values for `y` and `z` for the `left mouse click`.

#### Answer 2

Do not care about `Answer 1`, but you should use library `x` and this is how to do it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use JNA which can shield you from the complexities of the JNI (though of course JNA uses JNI itself)?  It's pretty straightforward to use and there's quite a bit of sample code out there, including in this forum.

Comment: :O That seems to fix more then 1 problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of Jintellitype and it was not designed for Mouse Input.  It has global keyboard hook only using the Windows MFC API.

Answer (score 0):

From http://melloware.com/products/jintellitype/index.html:

> JIntellitype is a Java API for interacting with Microsoft Intellitype commands as well as registering for Global Hotkeys in your Java application.

What makes you think it even has mouse support?

As an aside, I assume your complaint about JNI is that you don't want to *write* JNI code, and not that you don't even want to use it, because I'm pretty sure JIntellitype is using JNI.

Comment: Well I thought if I can not find a way to use `VK_LBUTTON = 0x01` (thats 1), then probably it can not, but might as well ask to be sure. And Yes, I don't like to use JNI directly.